# How to setup Dlib with Visual Studio 2013 without CMake? i

Tags: dlib

How to setup Dlib with Visual Studio 2013 without CMake? I found the tutorial but it not working a lot of error when I try to run the example file

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have to show us what you already did and ideally provide with information on what errors you are getting. Otherwise nobody will help.

Comment: @ramthaZ28 here is the link [link](https://aleen42.gitbooks.io/personalwiki/content/qa/dlib.html) try to use it. and tell us what kind of error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this link for setting [dlib](http://dlib.net/) in visual studio 2013.

**Setting Dlib in Visual studio 2013**

Create an empty console project and then follow steps

1. Set up the properties-

   In this step, you'll need to find out the Property Manager.

[image]

And then, you'll see that the manager will appear in your right bars, maybe when it's not for you, you can find it in other bars.

[image]

Open the project, you'll see two directory named **Debug|Win32** and **Release|Win32**. So in the next step, you should click each with right button of your mouse to **Add New Project Property Sheet**.

[image]

Here, you can see that I have created sheets for each directory, **dlib_debug** and **dlib_release**. What you should do is to find out **Common Properties > VC++ Directories**, and setup two properties, **Include Directories** and **Library Directories.**

[image]

The path you should set for your own is shown as follows(the path of dlib source files for me is F:\School\Programing\C++ Programing\OpenCV\Dlib\Lib\dlib, and of course you can use relative path)

[image]
[image]

In additionally, you should set up the preprocessor globaly for all the projects using Dlib.

[image]

Notice that *dlib_release** should be setup like dlib_debug.*

2. Include source.cpp

   For all projects using Dlib, the things you should do before is to include the source.cpp. Without it, Visual Studio will have given out some errors like cannot parse the external link.

[image]

3. Import all the external src files

   The last thing to do is to import all the external file from dlib\external. For clear structures, you can create some directories to distinguish them as what I did.

   Firstly, add existed items to the Source File Directory of your project.

[image]

And then choose all the files from dlib\external to add.

[image]

Finally, the dlib can be used after all those things have been done.